# Swift UITest - No match found for textField with accessibility identifier

Tags: swift, xcode, textfield, uitest

Trying to create a UITest for entering an email address/password into text fields and then hitting a login button. Using Xcode.

I watch the UITest navigate to the proper page, but it does not detect the text fields. I made sure that both text fields have the "Accessibility" box checked, and I've given them identifiers.

I'm getting this error:

> UI Testing Failure - No matches found for text field

```
func testExample() {
    let app = XCUIApplication()

    //Test login page
    app.buttons["loginButton"].tap()

    //Here it navigates to the desired page 
    let emailField = app.textFields["email"]
    emailField.tap()
    emailField.typeText("xxx.xx.edu")

    let passwordField = app.textFields["password"]
    passwordField.tap()
    passwordField.typeText("xxx")

    app.buttons["loginButton"].tap()

   // let loginAlert = app.alerts["alertVC"]

   // XCTAssertEqual(loginAlert.title, "Error")        
}
```

The accessibility indicators are "email" and "password" respectively. Logging in works fine when I run the simulator myself.

EDIT: Apparently there are no text fields at all (count = 0) even though I see them and use them on the page...

Image of storyboard with text fields:

[image]

Comment: I have the same problem  did you find a solution?

Answer (score 16):

If `UITextFiled` set `SecureTextEntry` **`true`**, you should use:

```
let passwordField = app.secureTextFields["password"]
```

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem and I solved by unchecking the "accessibility enabled" box for the "views" of ViewControllers